# I installed latest matplotlib version 1.5 from source, but version 1.3.1 is still working as a default one.

Tags: python, matplotlib, version

So as I explained the situation above. On Ubuntu I installed latest matplotlib version 1.5 from source with all dependencies and Eclipse seems to draw plots just fine, but version 1.3.1 of matplotlib is still working as a default one.

```
>> print (matplotlib.__version__)
1.3.1
```

I need to use styles from matplotlib which comes only from 1.4.X version. How I can make matplotlib version 1.5 default for my python3?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove `matplotlib` completely from your device.

This can be achieved using:

if you have installed it via `apt`

```
sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib
```

if you have installed it via `pip`

```
sudo pip uninstall matplotlib
```

After you have uninstalled it completely, try to install `matplotlib 1.5` and this should work. Somehow your previous version (i.e. `1.3.1`) is being taken as the default version even after installing `1.5.1`